# This operation is not allowed while editing error

Tags: arcobjects, editing, delete

When I tried to delete a feature, I got :This operation is not allowed while editing" error when I wanted to refresh version.

The related code is:

```
'Start Editing Operation
        lpWorkSpaceEdit.StartEditing(True)

        Do Until lpFeature Is Nothing
            Call CheckCPStatus(lpFeature, lbIsCPDead, lbIsCPNull)

            lpVerFC = lpObjSDEUtils.GetFeatureClass(lpCreatWS, lsLayerName)
            If Not lpVerFC.GetFeature(lpFeature.OID) Is Nothing Then
                lpVerFeat = lpVerFC.GetFeature(lpFeature.OID)
                lpVerFeat.Delete()

            End If

            'Iterate through the next feature
            lpFeature = lpFeatCursor.NextFeature
        Loop

        'Chech if the Created version has parent
        If lpCreatVer.HasParent Then
            lsParentVersionName = lpCreatVer.VersionInfo.Parent.VersionName
        Else
            MsgBox("You can only reconcile a version that has a parent.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "App")
        End If

        'Get the SDE Default's Latest Version
        'lpVersionEdit.Reconcile(lsParentVersionName)
        lpCreatVer.RefreshVersion()

        lpVersionEdit.Reconcile(lsParentVersionName)

        If lpVersionEdit.CanPost Then
            lpVersionEdit.Post(lsParentVersionName)
        End If

        'StopEditing Operation
        lpWorkSpaceEdit.StopEditing(True)

        lpVersionEdit.RefreshVersion()
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? How can I delete a feature properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sound and clear. You should refresh a version outside of an edit session.

> The RefreshVersion method refreshes the version to correspond with the
>   database state the version references. For example, if a second
>   application is editing the verison and saves their changes, you need
>   to call the RefreshVersion method to see the latest representation of
>   the version.

```
        ...
        If lpVersionEdit.CanPost Then
            lpVersionEdit.Post(lsParentVersionName)
        End If

        'StopEditing Operation
        lpWorkSpaceEdit.StopEditing(True)
        lpCreatVer.RefreshVersion()
```